# Как писать бек для react spa проекта?

Tags: reactjs, rest

Я пишу интернет магазин для портфолио на react сейчас нужно писать rest api бек на php. Проблема в том что одни говорят нужно создать другой проект и через мой проект сделать ajax на страницу goods например созданный мной другой проект example.com/goods чтоб взять список продуктов и обе проекта отделены на хостинге а другие говорят создать папку в проекте rest и там файл php взять список продуктов из базы например и через ajax взять от файла данные. Не понимаю как сделать. И если когда данные берем должны не в виде готового html а json формате данные и писать html на фронте ?

Answer (score 1):

Описание вопроса написано ужасно. Насколько я понял, вы имеете ввиду: "Сделать отдельный репозиторий для сервера или в этом же репозитории папочку server(rest), где будет весь код сервера." Если я не прав, то, прошу вас, поправьте меня.

То, делать ли server-side code отдельным проектом или же достаточно положить его в отдельную папку - решать вам. Вы можете ознакомиться с понятиями mono repository и multiple repository, может, сможете определиться. Насчет того, получает ли клиент готовую статику(html, css, js) или же отдаете клиенту пустой html, где вы получаете данные в виде json и потом их рендерите на клиенте , зависит от подхода к рендерингу. Чтобы уяснить этот вопроc, вам нужно ознакомиться с Client Side Rendering и Server Side Rendering. Очень прошу вас, поправьте меня в случае моей неправоты или неточности, а так же задавайте вопросы.

Comment: Я запутался так как одни говорят разделять на 2 проекта а другие говорят достаточно положить в отдельную папку.

Answer (score 0):

Не слушайте вы всех и меня в том числе. Вам нужен back сервис который ответит на запрос с клиента UI данные могут быть и рандомные с потолка хардкод это не важно. И на чем этот сервис тоже не важно это для портфолио, реализуйте все какие сможете веб сервисы.